# Using MySQL 5 , Simple Membership Provider, ASP.NET MVC4 with Entity Framework 5

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, simplemembership

I am trying to:
**use Simple Membership provider based authentication with MySQL using ASP.NET MVC 4** default web application configured to use MySQL using the tutorial given at:
http://www.nsilverbullet.net/2012/11/07/6-steps-to-get-entity-framework-5-working-with-mysql-5-5/

and here at [ASP.NET MVC 4 EF5 with MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12181428/asp-net-mvc-4-ef5-with-mysql)

I am using **MySQL Connector 6.6.4** with **EF 5.0** and **Visual Studio 2012** and working with an **ASP.NET MVC 4 Internet application** template.

### The errors i am facing is this:

```
Server Error in '/' Application.
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '[UserId] FROM [UserProfile] WHERE (UPPER([UserName]) = 'Z')' at line 1
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Exception Details: MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '[UserId] FROM [UserProfile] WHERE (UPPER([UserName]) = 'Z')' at line 1

Source Error:


Line 55:                     }
Line 56: 
Line 57:                     WebSecurity.InitializeDatabaseConnection("DefaultConnection", "UserProfile", "UserId", "UserName", autoCreateTables: false);
Line 58:                 }
Line 59:                 catch (Exception ex)


Source File: e:\Projects\TestApp\TestApp\TestApp\Filters\InitializeSimpleMembershipAttribute.cs    Line: 57
```

### My code is:

### InitializeSimpleMembershipAttribute.cs

```
private class SimpleMembershipInitializer
        {
            public SimpleMembershipInitializer()
            {
                //Database.SetInitializer<UsersContext>(null);
                //Database.SetInitializer(new DropCreateMySqlDatabaseIfModelChanges<UsersContext>());
                //Database.SetInitializer(new CreateMySqlDatabaseIfNotExists<UsersContext>());
                Database.SetInitializer(new DropCreateMySqlDatabaseIfModelChanges<UsersContext>());
                try
                {
                    using (var context = new UsersContext())
                    {
                        if (!context.Database.Exists())
                        {
                            // Create the SimpleMembership database without Entity Framework migration schema
                            //((IObjectContextAdapter)context).ObjectContext.CreateDatabase();
                            //context.Database.CreateIfNotExists();
                        }
                    }

                    WebSecurity.InitializeDatabaseConnection("DefaultConnection", "UserProfile", "UserId", "UserName", autoCreateTables: false);
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    throw new InvalidOperationException("The ASP.NET Simple Membership database could not be initialized. For more information, please see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=256588", ex);
                }
            }

        }
```

### AccountModel.cs (Relevant Code Only)

```
public class UsersContext : DbContext
    {
        static UsersContext()
        {
            //Database.SetInitializer(new DropCreateMySqlDatabaseIfModelChanges<UsersContext>());
        }
        public UsersContext()
            : base("DefaultConnection")
        {
            //Database.SetInitializer(new DropCreateMySqlDatabaseIfModelChanges<UsersContext>());
        }

        public DbSet<UserProfile> UserProfiles { get; set; }
    }
    public class DropCreateMySqlDatabaseAlways<TContext>
      : MySqlDatabaseInitializer<TContext> where TContext : DbContext
    {
        public override void InitializeDatabase(TContext context)
        {
            context.Database.Delete();
            CreateMySqlDatabase(context);
        }
    }

    public class DropCreateMySqlDatabaseIfModelChanges<TContext>
     : MySqlDatabaseInitializer<TContext> where TContext : DbContext
    {
        public override void InitializeDatabase(TContext context)
        {
            bool needsNewDb = false;
            if (context.Database.Exists())
            {
                if (!context.Database.CompatibleWithModel(false))
                {
                    context.Database.Delete();
                    needsNewDb = true;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                needsNewDb = true;
            }
            if (needsNewDb) CreateMySqlDatabase(context);
        }
    }

    public class CreateMySqlDatabaseIfNotExists<TContext>
   : MySqlDatabaseInitializer<TContext> where TContext : DbContext
    {
        public override void InitializeDatabase(TContext context)
        {
            if (context.Database.Exists())
            {
                if (!context.Database.CompatibleWithModel(false))
                {
                    throw new InvalidOperationException(
                        "The model has changed!");
                }
            }
            else
            {
                CreateMySqlDatabase(context);
            }
        }
    }

    public abstract class MySqlDatabaseInitializer<TContext>
     : IDatabaseInitializer<TContext>
         where TContext : DbContext
    {
        public abstract void InitializeDatabase(TContext context);

        protected void CreateMySqlDatabase(TContext context)
        {
            try
            {
                // Create as much of the database as we can
                context.Database.Create();

                // No exception? Don't need a workaround
                return;
            }
            catch (MySqlException ex)
            {
                // Ignore the parse exception
                if (ex.Number != 1064)
                {
                    throw;
                }
            }

            // Manually create the metadata table
            using (var connection = ((MySqlConnection)context
                .Database.Connection).Clone())
            using (var command = connection.CreateCommand())
            {
                command.CommandText =
    @"
CREATE TABLE __MigrationHistory (
    MigrationId mediumtext NOT NULL,
    Model mediumblob NOT NULL,
    ProductVersion mediumtext NOT NULL);

ALTER TABLE __MigrationHistory
ADD PRIMARY KEY (MigrationId(255));

INSERT INTO __MigrationHistory (
    MigrationId,
    Model,
    ProductVersion)
VALUES (
    'InitialCreate',
    @Model,
    @ProductVersion);
";
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue(
                    "@Model",
                    GetModel(context));
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue(
                    "@ProductVersion",
                    GetProductVersion());

                connection.Open();
                command.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
        }

        private byte[] GetModel(TContext context)
        {
            using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
            {
                using (var gzipStream = new GZipStream(
                    memoryStream,
                    CompressionMode.Compress))
                using (var xmlWriter = XmlWriter.Create(
                    gzipStream,
                    new XmlWriterSettings { Indent = true }))
                {
                    EdmxWriter.WriteEdmx(context, xmlWriter);
                }

                return memoryStream.ToArray();
            }
        }

        private string GetProductVersion()
        {
            return typeof(DbContext).Assembly
                .GetCustomAttributes(false)
                .OfType<AssemblyInformationalVersionAttribute>()
                .Single()
                .InformationalVersion;
        }
    }

    [Table("UserProfile")]
    public class UserProfile
    {
        [Key]
        [DatabaseGeneratedAttribute(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        public int UserId { get; set; }
        public string UserName { get; set; }
    }

    public class RegisterExternalLoginModel
    {
        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "User name")]
        public string UserName { get; set; }

        public string ExternalLoginData { get; set; }
    }

    public class LocalPasswordModel
    {
        [Required]
        [DataType(DataType.Password)]
        [Display(Name = "Current password")]
        public string OldPassword { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [StringLength(100, ErrorMessage = "The {0} must be at least {2} characters long.", MinimumLength = 6)]
        [DataType(DataType.Password)]
        [Display(Name = "New password")]
        public string NewPassword { get; set; }

        [DataType(DataType.Password)]
        [Display(Name = "Confirm new password")]
        [Compare("NewPassword", ErrorMessage = "The new password and confirmation password do not match.")]
        public string ConfirmPassword { get; set; }
    }
```

Kindly help me finding out what i am doing wrong. Thanks

Comment: You need to confirm the queries your trying to use actually work. Because the error your getting indicates they are not correct.  Besides you didn't even post the code with the actual query in it why?

Comment: I have not written any query at all. If there is any code, its inside the SimpleMembership provider implementation. I am using the template defaults, i donot have any queries written at all in my code. It is the default ASP.NET MVC4 Internet Application template that works seamlessley with SQL Server and i am trying to configure the same with MySQL. If you follow the urls i have provided, you will know what i mean.

Comment: You are going to need to implement your own provider if you want to use MySQL as your database backend.  The error is clear the query that is being used currently is flawed.

Comment: Hmm..This article seems like they have done with out it. http://www.nsilverbullet.net/2012/11/07/6-steps-to-get-entity-framework-5-working-with-mysql-5-5/ Can you have a look please?

Comment: From a linked page on the blog: **But beware the MySql providers do not currently support the ASP.NET 4.5 templates since those templates use ExtendedMembershipProvider and SimpleMembershipProvider and they have an internal dependency on MS SQL Server.** so actually they implemented their own provider.  http://www.nsilverbullet.net/2012/11/06/using-mysql5-as-membership-backend-for-aspnet45-mvc4-application/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I provided an answer on a similar question here:
[Using Simple Membership Provider with mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12620922/using-simple-membership-provider-with-mysql/15800614#15800614)
It's based on a article from Fabio Costa I found here: http://fabiocosta.ca/2012/11/24/use-simplemembership-and-oauth-with-any-database-and-datatype/. You basically get the source code, update it to your needs (let it write mysql queries instead of sql) and use that.

Answer (score 1):

It may be true that you can use MySQL with EF, as I do this myself, but it seems that the Simple Membership Provider is not supported.

Read the answer at the bottom of this post:
http://forums.asp.net/t/1766451.aspx/1

Answer (score -1):

Please have a look at https://mysqlmembershipprovider.codeplex.com/

and the providers are implemented using EF too, and default build on .NET 4.5.