# To call this method, the “Membership.Provider” property must be an instance of “ExtendedMembershipProvider”

Tags: mysql, asp.net-mvc

I am working on Asp.Net WebAPI Project. I am using MySQL Membership provider. While creating account I get the following Exception:

> To call this method, the “Membership.Provider” property must be an instance of “ExtendedMembershipProvider”

**Web.Config**

```
 <membership defaultProvider="MySQLMembershipProvider">
  <providers>
    <clear/>
    <add name="MySQLMembershipProvider" type="MySql.Web.Security.MySQLMembershipProvider, MySql.Web, Version=6.9.7.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d" connectionStringName="DefaultConnectionString" enablePasswordRetrieval="false" enablePasswordReset="true" requiresQuestionAndAnswer="true" applicationName="/" requiresUniqueEmail="false" passwordFormat="Clear" maxInvalidPasswordAttempts="5" minRequiredPasswordLength="7" minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="1" passwordAttemptWindow="10" passwordStrengthRegularExpression="" />
  </providers>
</membership>

  <profile defaultProvider="MySQLProfileProvider" enabled="true">
    <providers>
      <clear />
      <add type="MySql.Web.Profile.MySQLProfileProvider, MySql.Web, Version=6.8.3, Culture=neutral" name="MySqlProfileProvider" applicationName="/" connectionStringName="DefaultConnectionString" autogenerateschema="true" />
    <remove name="MySQLProfileProvider" />
      <add name="MySQLProfileProvider" type="MySql.Web.Profile.MySQLProfileProvider, MySql.Web, Version=6.9.7.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d" connectionStringName="DefaultConnectionString" applicationName="/" /></providers>
  </profile>

  <roleManager enabled="true" defaultProvider="MySQLRoleProvider">
    <providers>
      <clear />
      <add connectionStringName="DefaultConnectionString" applicationName="/" name="MySqlRoleProvider" type="MySql.Web.Security.MySQLRoleProvider, MySql.Web" autogenerateschema="true" />
    <remove name="MySQLRoleProvider" /><add name="MySQLRoleProvider" type="MySql.Web.Security.MySQLRoleProvider, MySql.Web, Version=6.9.7.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d" connectionStringName="DefaultConnectionString" applicationName="/" /></providers>
  </roleManager>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use membership provider, first you need to initialize(InitializeDatabaseConnection) membership provider in AppStart

[Using MySQL 5 , Simple Membership Provider, ASP.NET MVC4 with Entity Framework 5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14959442/using-mysql-5-simple-membership-provider-asp-net-mvc4-with-entity-framework-5)

[Using Simple Membership Provider with mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12620922/using-simple-membership-provider-with-mysql)