# Connection string not working with MySQL

Tags: mysql, entity-framework

I am creating a `REST API` using `MySQL DB` in `visual studio 2015 in asp.net mvc 4.5`. I have done each and every step which in needed to run the API using `MySQL`, but I am getting this exception.

> {"Message":"An error has occurred.","ExceptionMessage":"**Format of the initialization string does not conform to specification starting at index 121.**","ExceptionType":"System.ArgumentException","StackTrace":"   at System.Data.Common.DbConnectionOptions.GetKeyValuePair(String connectionString, Int32 currentPosition, StringBuilder buffer, Boolean useOdbcRules, String& keyname, String& keyvalue)\r\n   at System.Data.Common.DbConnectionOptions.ParseInternal(Hashtable parsetable, String connectionString, Boolean buildChain, Hashtable synonyms, Boolean firstKey)\r\n   at System.Data.Common.DbConnectionOptions..ctor(String connectionString, Hashtable synonyms, Boolean useOdbcRules)\r\n   at System.Data.Common.DbConnectionStringBuilder.set_ConnectionString(String value)\r\n   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnectionStringBuilder..ctor(String connStr)\r\n   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection.set_ConnectionString(String value)\r\n   at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.DbConnectionDispatcher.b__18(DbConnection t, DbConnectionPropertyInterceptionContext`1 c)\r\n   at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.InternalDispatcher`1.Dispatch[TTarget,TInterceptionContext](TTarget target, Action`2 operation, TInterceptionContext interceptionContext, Action`3 executing, Action`3 executed)\r\n   at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.DbConnectionDispatcher.SetConnectionString(DbConnection connection, DbConnectionPropertyInterceptionContext`1 interceptionContext)\r\n   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalConnection.InitializeFromConnectionStringSetting(ConnectionStringSettings appConfigConnection)\r\n   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalConnection.TryInitializeFromAppConfig(String name, AppConfig config)\r\n   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalConnection.Initialize()\r\n   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalConnection.CreateObjectContextFromConnectionModel()\r\n   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.InitializeContext()\r\n   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.GetEntitySetAndBaseTypeForType(Type entityType)\r\n   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.Initialize()\r\n   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.GetEnumerator()\r\n   at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbQuery`1.System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<TResult>.GetEnumerator()\r\n   at System.Collections.Generic.List`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 collection)\r\n   at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)\r\n   at RestWithMySQL.Controllers.ProductsController.Get() in D:\Work\DOT NET API\RestWithMySQL\RestWithMySQL\Controllers\ProductsController.cs:line 19"}

I think there is a problem in my connection string. I have searched for it but couldn't find the exact solution.

```
<connectionStrings>
    <!--<add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDb)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\aspnet-RestWithMySQL-20170911031521.mdf;Initial Catalog=aspnet-RestWithMySQL-20170911031521;Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />-->
    <add name="ProductEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/ProductsModel.csdl|res://*/ProductsModel.ssdl|res://*/ProductsModel.msl;provider=MySql.Data.MySqlClient;provider connection string=&quot; server=localhost;user id=root;database=accurate_dev;integrated security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework" providerName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient"/>
    <!--<remove name="LocalMySqlServer" /><add name="LocalMySqlServer" connectionString="" providerName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" />-->
</connectionStrings>
```

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Not sure if this is the issue but have you tried changing `&quot;` to `"`?

Answer (score 8):

Strip down your connection string to the bare minimum.  Add options back and see what causes it to fail.  For example `integrated security=true` is not going to work with MySQL.  You will need to add a `password` instead.

Form here:
[ASP.NET MVC 4 EF5 with MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12181428/asp-net-mvc-4-ef5-with-mysql)

Try something closer to this:

`<add name="DefaultConnection"
   providerName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient"
   connectionString="Data Source=localhost;port=3306;Initial Catalog=api_db;User Id=root;password=''"/>`

Comment: I have changed the connection string but now i am getting this `The context is being used in Code First mode with code that was generated from an EDMX file for either Database First or Model First development.  This will not work correctly. To fix this problem do not remove the line of code that throws this exception.`

Answer (score 2):

Shouldn't your connection string have another quote in it at the end?

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="ProductEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/ProductsModel.csdl|res://*/ProductsModel.ssdl|res://*/ProductsModel.msl;provider=MySql.Data.MySqlClient;provider connection string=&quot; server=localhost;user id=root;database=accurate_dev;integrated security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient"/>
</connectionStrings>
```

Further:
In order to use the MySQL provider, consider these steps provided [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20277677/dynamic-mysql-database-connection-for-entity-framework-6/20294903#20294903)

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a closing &quot; at the end of your connection string.