# error while making connection in mvc .net (system.data.common.dbconnection)

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

i am new to the mvc and trying to connect my mysql database to the application using mvc..

my connection string is as-

```
<connectionString>
    <add name ="Controlsheetlogin" connectionString="Server=localhost; database=test;User Id=root;password=123"/>
</connectionString>
```

[this is my connection string](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p1u8M.jpg)

and am getting error in **MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand** 
thanks in advance for any help.

[and this is the error that i am getting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/us6in.jpg)

Comment: You could search for that error instead. Maybe there's a question on Stack Overflfow to help you with this specific case.

Comment: Could you post the C# method where you are getting the error assuming it is relevant?

Comment: It would be helpful to include the exception in the text.

Comment: string constr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["abc"].ConnectionString          using (MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection(constr))                     
 { using (MySqlCommand cmd  = new MySqlCommand() )                 am getting error in using

Answer (score 0):

Your connection string does not look right. To Connect EF to MySQL you need to specify the provider as such:

```
[...] name="ConnectionString" providerName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" [...]
```

Answers to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12181428/asp-net-mvc-4-ef5-with-mysql) may be helpful, as it details how to set up EF with MySQL.

Comment: From the screen shot of the errors you are getting you seem to be missing a number of references... Could you post your C# code so we can help you further?

Comment: I meant to edit your question with the relevant C# code (at least the full using block like you have in a comment but it's hard to read) and the using(s) declaration at the top as the errors message point to missing references...