# Where is the error in my Web.config file when trying to use MySQL Connector for .NET?

Tags: mysql, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, web-config

I am using Visual Studio to create a MVC app. I'm trying to use the MySQL Connector for .NET to communicate with the database on AWS. I followed the instructions on the MySQL documentation and I still get this error:

> System.InvalidOperationException: 'The DbConfiguration type
> 'MySql.Data.Entity.MySqlEFConfiguration, MySql.Data.EntityFramework'
> specified in the application config file could not be loaded.
> Make
> sure that the assembly-qualified name is used and that the assembly is
> available to the running application.

Here is the <system.data> section:

```
  <system.data>
    <DbProviderFactories>
      <remove invariant="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" />
      <add name="MySQL Data Provider" invariant="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" description=".Net Framework Data Provider for MySQL" type="MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlClientFactory, MySql.Data" />
    </DbProviderFactories>
  </system.data>
```

I didn't specify the Version or Key because all the examples I found have different numbers.

Comment: Look at the following post: [ASP.NET MVC 4 EF5 with MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12181428/6630084)

Comment: And this one [https://stackoverflow.com/a/21954322](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21954322). It's seems like the problem in provider configuration section (part of the app.conf).